# Python - Syntax error for taking minimum of tuple by second element

Tags: syntax, python-2.7, tuples, minimum

I want to create a list of tuples with first element from a list, and the second element from a function of the element of list, then find the minimum from the output of the function.
The code below best explains what I want:

```
x,y = min((x,f(x) for x in array), key = lambda(k, v): v[1])
```

After running the script, I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

NOTE: f(x) returns int/float

---

**Update**: I wrote my code from another stack overflow question, so I didnt know what exactly I was doing. Can someone explains how key works?
Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Python 2 or 3? In python 3, you cannot use the parenthesis in the lambda expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, Python 2! Since someone downvoted my question, I can no longer upvote the answer, lol –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
x,y = min(((x,f(x)) for x in array), key = lambda(k, v): v)
```

Comment: Accepted for understanding intent! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some parenthesis:

```
x, y = min(((x,f(x)) for x in array), key = lambda t: t[1][1])
```

I adjusted the lambda expression to work in both Python 2 and 3 (where you cannot use tuple unpacking in the parameter list).

Remember that the key is just a function that is supposed to return the value for which we want to know the minimum. It is called for each element in the input sequence. In this case that's a `(x, f(x))` tuple, and you wanted to find the minimum by the second element of the `f(x)` return value.

Answer (score 1):

In your list comprehension, the `,` is not parsed as a tuple expression.  You need to wrap it with `()` to make the parser know.

```
x,y = min(( (x,f(x)) for x in array), key = lambda(k, v): v[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Either add the missing parentheses, or rewrite the code like so:

```
y, x = min(zip(map(f, array), array))
```

I've swapped the order of the tuple elements to not have to supply a key function to `min()`.

Here is another version:

```
x = min(array, key=f)
y = f(x)
```

It's short and clear, but makes an additional call to `f()`.

Comment: What if I try:   

x, y = min(array, key=f), f(x)